# Clustering WSO2 IdentityServer without (Distributed) Cache

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Because of memory leaks after enabling the [distributed caching](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Multi-tenant+Caching+based+on+Hazelcast) in WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 (similar to: [WSO2 JIRA IDENTITY-5050](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5050) ) based on the [WSO2 Clustering Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0+and+5.2.0) I thought I would try a different approach for my  cluster of multiple active instances (for high availability), by disabling caching and trusting the database will scale enough for my purposes.

I disabled quite a few caches through the identity.xml below:

```
<CacheConfig>
    <CacheManager name="IdentityApplicationManagementCacheManager">
        <Cache name="AppAuthFrameworkSessionContextCache"
                                                 enable="false" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="AuthenticationContextCache" enable="true" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="AuthenticationRequestCache" enable="true" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="AuthenticationResultCache"  enable="true" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="AppInfoCache"               enable="true"  timeout="900" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="AuthorizationGrantCache"    enable="false" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="OAuthCache"                 enable="true" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="OAuthScopeCache"            enable="true"  timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="OAuthSessionDataCache"      enable="true" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="SAMLSSOParticipantCache"    enable="true" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="SAMLSSOSessionIndexCache"   enable="true" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="SAMLSSOSessionDataCache"    enable="true" timeout="300" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="ServiceProviderCache"       enable="true"  timeout="900" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="ProvisioningConnectorCache" enable="true"  timeout="900" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="ProvisioningEntityCache"    enable="true" timeout="900" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="ServiceProviderProvisioningConnectorCache"
                                                 enable="true"  timeout="900" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="IdPCacheByAuthProperty"     enable="false"  timeout="900" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="IdPCacheByHRI"              enable="false"  timeout="900" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
        <Cache name="IdPCacheByName"             enable="false"  timeout="900" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
    </CacheManager>
    <CacheManager name="IDENTITY_LOGIN_DATA_CACHE_MANAGER">
        <Cache name="IDENTITY_LOGIN_DATA_CACHE"  enable="false" timeout="1" capacity="5000" isDistributed="false"/>
    </CacheManager>
</CacheConfig>
```

But I failed to disable the cache of the JDBCIdentityDataStore which uses the IDENTITY_LOGIN_DATA_CACHE (defined in parent class InMemoryIdentityDataStore). This is crucial for account locking information in a time where users use a different internet connection for their laptop (WIFI) then they receive there activation email (cellular data connection) and after activating it wonder why their account is still disabled.

I'm open for suggestions besides my own:

1. disable the IDENTITY_LOGIN_DATA_CACHE (not sure how yet)
2. switch from active-active to active-passive to decrease the chance of problems (hurts horizontal scalability)
3. migrate from the default JDBCIdentityDataStore to the UserStoreBasedIdentityDataStore based on the docs at https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/User+Account+Locking+and+Account+Disabling  (hoping it has no cache or can be disabled through configuration)
4. Change the [DefaultCacheTimeout](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Performance+Tuning) from 15 to 1 minutes (hoping it takes the user longer to activate the account and login)

Comment: try to use IP addresses in the hazelcast cluster config instead of hostnames, it helped us

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However in our case according to netstat and tcpdump -i any port 4000 we had active connections over the cluster port 4000 between the nodes (after making sure we used FQDN's for the WKA that resolved and had Docker port forwarding enabled) but then we ended up with a memory leak and I'm not sure whether all the different caches were consistent over the cluster - and I have no idea how to check this. This question focuses on how to run wso2 clusters without caches enabled.

Comment: Imho your setup will work without some features (token revocation between nodes..). We had a memleak on wso2is 5.1.0 and using ip instead of fqdn helped. I believe the current version of wso2is has the issue solved (it was something with hazelcast connection naming)

Comment: [CARBON-14573](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14573) supports it as best practice to use addresses instead of DNS names. However loads of other (fixed) bugs like [CARBON-15926](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15926) and [16074](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-16074) are not very encouraging.

Comment: Did you figure out how to stop the IDENTITY_LOGIN_DATA_CACHE cache? It's also messing with me

Comment: No, we implemented an active/passive cluster instead of active/active with our load balancer to work around the problem.